# Is there a way to use an IF statement to track if another user changed the data in a table and time stamp it?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an access database in which multiple customers will be placing large orders on a weekly basis. I have a query automatically set up in excel to refresh the information every minute. A potential issue I could see happening: Manager places order in our access form, decides to edit his record later w/o contacting the scheduler, and changes the order information he originally entered. I would like to track what it was changed from and to, as well as the date they changed it. These orders have to be placed by a certain time in the week for them to make the shipment in or out the following Monday. If orders are changed, I want to know. If orders are changed after the deadline, I especially want to know. Thanks

Comment: Don't let them make a change in Access the same way they enter new data, have a specific change form and then you can get the before and after by appending to a log and modifying the record after.

Comment: Context: I am a new hire operation analyst. I suggested this, however the schedulers suggested that they believe that some of the less 'techy' people who have to order could easily mistake this... lol... So I am trying to accommodate both sides. The tables are hidden.. The only thing the orderer will be able to see is the new order form. In which I'm 99% sure that no one will go to the extremes of unhiding the tables and altering the records w/o notifying the scheduler, but who knows. Trying to get ahead of potential issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a before update event that inserts the changes into an audit log table. Here is the resource I used for my databases: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-simple-solution-for-tracking-changes-to-access-data/

Note: This will only track changes made to existing records through the form. It also will not track deletions or changes made directly in the table.

Comment: Awesome! This is definitely a solution I will consider. Thank you much.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If all goes well, please consider marking this answer as correct.